# Read only shared memory between C#->C++

Tags: c#, c++, interop

,I have C# code that creates 3D geometry and sends it to a C++ library to be rendered. At the moment the data is passed over interop like so (I've reduced the number of arrays passed):

```
void LoadMeshData(Mesh meshData)
        {
            var verticesArraySize = meshData.Vertices.Length;
            unsafe
            {                
                fixed (float* vertices = meshData.Vertices)
                {
                    Interop.Data.MeshDataObject meshDataObject;
                    meshDataObject.vertexArraySize = verticesArraySize;
                    meshDataObject.vertexData = new IntPtr(vertices);
                    SceneInterop.AddMeshData(meshDataObject);
                }
            }
```

`Interop.Data.MeshDataObject` is a POD struct that matches a similar struct on the C++ side.

The `fixed` obviously goes out of scope after this call, so at the moment I'm copying the array into a structure in C++. This is clearly a huge waste of memory, so ideally I'd like a way to mark the C# memory as permanently "fixed" - is this feasible?
I only ever need to read the data in the C++ library, and I do need to keep it available on the C# side.
Any other suggestions on how I can save myself the copying?

Comment: You can use GCHandle to create a pinned handle, but it will undermine the efficiency of the GC. You may ask the C++ code to allocate the memory and return the pointer to C#.

Comment: That C++ code needs another function, something like float* CreateMeshStorage(size_t size)

Comment: The C# code shouldn't be dependent on the C++ stuff so the pinned handle sounds like the way forwards. Looks like I can just get a handle to an existing array as well which is handy

Comment: "This is clearly a huge waste of memory" - Have you measured? Sometimes it may be worth it to sacrifice a few MB of memory to get cleaner code, or reduce the risk of bugs.

Comment: Use `Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem` then create a `Memory<byte>` from it. Don't forget to free when done.

Comment: @JonasH yes, I’m talking about large 3D models here, several Gb - so the duplication is a real problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question here but it is really just the first comment above, [@shingo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6196568/shingo) please feel free to put it in as an answer and I'll remove this one.

> You can use GCHandle to create a pinned handle, but it will undermine the efficiency of the GC. You may ask the C++ code to allocate the memory and return the pointer to C#

I used `verticesHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(vertices, GCHandleType.Pinned)` which lets me share memory nicely.
Later when I'm happy to allow removal of the memory I use

```
if (verticesHandle.IsAllocated)
    verticesHandle.Free();
```